# Post body not being sent in gitlabci when using yml

Tags: curl, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I am struggling to make a post request via CURL in my gitlabci file. I am attempting to post to an API, however, the body does not seem to be sent for some reason.

I have tested my curl request in various online validators as well as importing in postman, this all seems to work correctly.

[gitlabci file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXlXF.png)

The request authenticates correctly through our API, the body (-d) is simply not sent
Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

```
update:
    stage: update
    script:
         - >- 
            curl -X POST -v --location "www.example.com/example" \ 
            -H "Authorization: Api-Token anAPiToken"  \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
            -d '{   "entitySelector": "entityId(SERVICE-8E3722AC3F76B09D)",
                    "eventType": "CUSTOM_DEPLOYMENT",
                    "title": "New Deployment Triggered",  
                    "properties": { 
                        "RemediationUrl": "www.example.com/example"
                    }
                }'
```

Sending -d in a single line
Various different ways of using Curl within the gitlabci based on suggestions on other SO questions

Comment: Please add the relevant code as text, not as a linked image. Otherwise this post will not be very helpful for others in the future.

Comment: Code Added as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this in GitHub actions, but the principle should be the same for GitLab.

Currently your script evaluates to this:

```
 curl -X POST -v --location "www.example.com/example" \  -H "Authorization: Api-Token anAPiToken"  \ -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \ -d '{   "entitySelector": "entityId(SERVICE-8E3722AC3F76B09D)",
          "eventType": "CUSTOM_DEPLOYMENT",
          "title": "New Deployment Triggered",  
          "properties": { 
              "RemediationUrl": "www.example.com/example"
          }
      }'
```

Notice the extra `\` characters in between. I assume you tried to add intentional line continuation on those lines, and not on the last JSON body part. However, that's not how it works.

`>-` basically breaks down to two components:

- `>` strips all interior line breaks except the last one
- `-` is a [*chomping indicator*](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2-old/spec.html#chomping//) "*Stripping is specified by the “-” chomping indicator. In this case, the final line break and any trailing empty lines are excluded from the scalar’s content.* "

So in other words, you don't need to specify the line continuations by yourself with `\`, those are already automatically stripped.

So basically, this should work:

```
        script:
          - >- 
            curl -X POST -v --location "www.example.com/example"
            -H "Authorization: Api-Token anAPiToken"
            -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"
            -d '{   "entitySelector": "entityId(SERVICE-8E3722AC3F76B09D)",
                    "eventType": "CUSTOM_DEPLOYMENT",
                    "title": "New Deployment Triggered",  
                    "properties": { 
                        "RemediationUrl": "www.example.com/example"
                    }
                }'
```

However, note that this will output everything on a single line. If you for some reason need and want the linebreaks on the POST body content, see [How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-in-yaml-over-multiple-lines) for more information.